# Equation not fitting the slide

Tags: beamer, equations

I have a beamer code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My slide with equation alongwith figure (on the left)}



   \begin{tabular}{cl}
   \begin{tabular}{c}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Tree}
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}{l}
        \parbox{0.1\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \begin{equation*}
                    \mathcal{H}(k) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
                        0 & v(t) + w(t) e^{i k a} \\ 
                        v(t) + w(t) e^{-i k a} & 0
                    \end{array}\right)
                \end{equation*}
            \end{itemize}   

        }
    \end{tabular}  \\
    \end{tabular}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But equation is going out of the box, and making the slide ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spacing can be improved:

- By removing the inner tables that add additional `\tabcolsep` spacing.
- By using environment `bmatrix` of package `amsmath` for the matrix.

The following example removes the outermost left and right `\tabcolsep` and scales the image to the available place.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newdimen\TempDimen
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My slide with equation alongwith figure (on the left)}

  \setlength{\TempDimen}{.767\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{}}
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \includegraphics[
        width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\TempDimen-2\tabcolsep\relax
      ]{example-image}%
    }
    & \parbox[t]{\TempDimen}{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item
          $\displaystyle
            \mathcal{H}(k) =
            \begin{pmatrix}
              0 & v(t) + w(t) e^{i k a} \\
              v(t) + w(t) e^{-i k a} & 0
            \end{pmatrix}
          $%
        \end{itemize}%
      }\\
  \end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The right side can be made smaller:

- Smaller font, e.g. `\small` (smaller sizes are not recommended. If nobody can read the equation, then the equation can be omitted.)
- Two lines (left side and right side of the equation in different lines).
- Or consider a different layout or representation.

Answer (score 3):

We neither have your real image nor the document setup, but you can follow these tips:

1. Use `pmatrix` from amsmath, it's more compact
2. Get rid of itemize, no real need here for it
3. `tabularx` makes it easy to utilize full linewidth automatically
4. Use `multline` to break the equation over two lines
5. You may also use a slightly smaller `\small` or `\footnotesize` font, in this case, you may not use `multline` or that `parbox`, just two `$` signs will be OK.
6. Finally, notice that `$\vcenter{\hbox{..}}$` to vertically center the image automatically.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My slide with equation alongwith figure (on the left)}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX@{}}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}}$
&
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{H}(k) = \\ \begin{pmatrix}{cc}
0 & v(t) + w(t) e^{i k a} \\ 
v(t) + w(t) e^{-i k a} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{multline*}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Beamer has its own environment for this situation: `columns`. And I also adopted the `pmatrix` from Heiko's answer. (And I didn't quite understand what the itemize is good for here but it is straightforward to resurrect.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My slide with equation alongwith figure (on the left)}


\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{4cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{8cm}
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{H}(k) = \begin{pmatrix}
                  0 & v(t) + w(t)\, e^{\mathrm{i} k a} \\ 
                        v(t) + w(t)\, e^{-\mathrm{i} k a} & 0
                    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with `tabularx` and `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My slide with equation alongwith figure (on the left)}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c@{}X@{}}
      \includegraphics[width=0.22\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image}
    &   \vspace*{-2pt}
        \begin{itemize}
    \item   $\displaystyle
            \mathcal{H}(k) = \begin{pmatrix}
                              0 & v(t) + w(t) e^{i k a} \\
                              v(t) + w(t) e^{-i k a} & 0
                            \end{pmatrix}
            $
        \end{itemize}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]